# decoding mod_rewrite charactors

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm attempting my first pretty url implementation via mod_rewrite. Just want to check if I'm on the right track. I'm doing it via dev environment.

I'm trying to get `www.cysticlife.dev/Profile.php?id=34` to become `www.cysticlife.dev/34/Profile`

Would the regex mod_rewrite version then be:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/?/Profile$ www.cysticlife.dev/Profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work and yielded the Not Found

The requested URL /34/Profile was not found on this server error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/Profile/index.html$ /$1/Profile [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/Profile/$ /$1/Profile [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/Profile$ www.cysticlife.dev/Profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The "?/" wasn't needed.
The lines I added makes both www.cysticlife.dev/34/Profile, www.cysticlife.dev/34/Profile**/** and www.cysticlife.dev/34/Profile**/index.html** work (with a 301 "Permanently moved" redirection so only one of the three urls is indexed by search engines).

Sidenote: You don't need to specify the full url for your rewrite. You could easily replace the last one with:

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/Profile$ www.cysticlife.dev/Profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What is your server configuration? This is working fine on my dev environment with Apache.

Are you sure your php script starts with a capital "P" and not a lowercase? Other issues can come from the rewrite_mod not activated/included in your server.

Comment: I know for a fact that mod_rewrite is enabled on my real server but this is on my dev. Let me double check. thanks

Comment: @LightningWrist Keep me informed, I'm curious because these are exactly the lines I use on my own website though enclosed with:
    
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     ...
    </IfModule>

Stupid suggestion (but w/ever, I guess you know how quickly a small mistake is done and bugs us for hours...), did you check if you could access www.cysticlife.dev/Profile.php?id=34 without url-rewriting?

Comment: course buddy. I'll keep you posted. Thanks for you time and care